# The norm of the derivative of a matrix with respect to a vector

Tags: partial-derivative, tensor-products, inverse, matrix-norms, contraction-mapping

Let $A(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a matrix depending on a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. What can we say about the derivative of $f(x) = (\tau A(x)- I)^{-1}x_0$ with respect to $\tau > 0$ and $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$? Are there any simplifications?
For the context of the problem, I am looking for a $\tau = \tau(x,x_0)$ such that $\lVert D_xf(x) \rVert < 1$ holds for a skew-symmetric matrix $A(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\l{\tau}
\def\G{{\Gamma}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}  \def\mt{\mapsto}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$For typing convenience, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
b &= x_0 &\qiq db = dx_0 \\
C &= \LR{I-A\l}^{-1} &\qiq \c{dC = C\LR{A\:d\l}C} \\
}$$
Calculate the differential of the function
$$\eqalign{
f &= -Cb \\
df &= -\c{dC}\,b \;-\; C\,db \\
 &= -\c{C\LR{A\:d\l}C}b \;-\; C\,db \\
 &= \LR{CAf}d\l \;-\; C\,db  \\
}$$
from which the required gradients are easily identified
$$\eqalign{
\grad f\l &= CAf, \qquad\quad \grad fb &= -C \\
}$$